# Cygwin: Libcurl Not Working

Tags: c, curl, cygwin, libcurl

I can't seem to get libcurl to work. I've installed it with the cygwin package installer but when I run it in the cygwin bash shell with:

```
gcc -Wall -lcurl -g blah.c -o blah
```

It I get:

> curl/curl.h: No such file or directory`,

then following errors that provoked by the `#include <curl/curl.h>` not working.

Comment: Are you sure you have libcurl installed?

Comment: @shinkou Not at all! I'm a beginner, I don't know.

Comment: `rpm -aq | grep curl` and see.

Comment: when I type that in cygwin it says: "bash: rpm: command not found"

Comment: I think your installation is incomplete.  Try add those packages from the installer.

Comment: I've tried installing it 2 times... It won't work

Comment: @Downvoter: please explain why you've downvoted this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find / -name curl.h
```

if curl.h is found, compile with this:

```
-I/directory/that/contains_the_curl_header
```

but do not include 'curl.h', just the directory containing it. If you are doing it like this:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
```

then only use the directory that contains the curl directory as the `-I` parameter.

man gcc for more info.

Comment: I don't think that it found it.

Comment: Maybe you need the curl-devel package (which has all the header files, development man pages and other development related files in it). libcurl package on it's own will only have the dynamic/static libraries.

Comment: @Drav It looks like the devel package is obsolete.  http://www.cygwin.com/packages/

Comment: I've downloaded libcurl devel and now in C:\cygwin\usr\include\curl there is a curl.h but how do I include it in my file now?

Comment: That will be as Tom suggested, add `-I/usr/include` (which _should_ be searched by default) to your gcc command

Comment: Now I'm getting lots of warnings and my program still isnt compiling and they start with: "In file included from /cygwin/usr/include/curl.h:64"

Comment: Is there a way I can just compile it from my mac into a .exe, I really can't figure this out.

Comment: @Nile, you can link statically, but making a '.exe' from your mac I think is doubtful. Shouldn't be necessary, as cURL is cross platform.